# Update table on base of checkboxes,

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hello Hope every one will be good. I have a problem.

I have a form following form code.

```php
<form name="form3" method="post" action="">

    <?php while ($row_news1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_news1)) { ?>

<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="1" <?php if($row_news1['house']=='1') echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>>


<input type="checkbox" name="check2[]" value="1" <?php if($row_news1['add_item']=='1') echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>>



<input type="text" name="user_name[]" id="textfield" readonly style="width:50%;color:white;background-color:transparent" value="<?php echo $row_news1['FirstName'].'&nbsp;'.$row_news1['LastName'];  ?>"><br>


<input type="hidden" name="user_id[]" value="<?php echo $row_news1['UserID']; ?>">


<?php } ?>


<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="update" class="but">     

<input type="submit" value="Reset" name="reset" class="but">

</form>
```

I want that how much the user name record comes to an array. That much time the two check boxes will be Generated. So when i checked all the check boxes so the table update successfully. But when i want to checked some check boxes randomly.so their corresponding record will be update with Value 1 and all other unchecked check boxes Corresponding Record will be updated with the Value of 0.

Here is my Form Submission code.

```php
if(isset($_POST['update'])&& $_POST['user_name']!=''){  // checking if Update button clicked

 $user_id=$_POST['user_id']; // Getting all user_id

 $user_name= $_POST['user_name']; //Getting user name text box

 $check1=$_POST['check1'];// Getting all check boxes but in this case its only taking checked boxes.

 $check2=$_POST['check2'];


        for($i = 0; $i < count($user_name); $i++){ // iterating the code until we have user name.

            if($check1[$i]=='1'){ // checked if first checkbox value is 1 so assign 1 to Variable a. other wise 0;

                $a=1;

            }

            else {

                $a=0;


            }

            if($check2[$i]=='1'){ // same as above i want

                $b=1;

            }

            else {

                $b=0;

            }

           // this is the query that i want to update the rocord

            $query_u1 = "UPDATE Users

                SET

                house = '".$a."',

                add_item = '".$b."'

                WHERE UserID=".$user_id[$i];

        mysql_query($query_u1) or die(mysql_error());


        }

        echo '<script> window.location = "adminmain.php";</script>';

}
```

The above code shows my Php and mysql query code.

Now i Want that i get all check boxes checked or not. just the other things. Means i have 10 Record for users. Every record have their UserId and name. With Every Record I have Two check Boxes as show in code.

I want when i checked 5 check boxes Randomly. so these five corresponding record will be updated with 1 value. and other five check boxes corresponding record will updated with 0 value.

I think you people will got it now.

Comment: I understand English is not your first language, that's fine, but could you try to re-explain the question again? I don't understand at all, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I Wants when i submitted the form through Submit button. So I will get the checked check boxes value which is 1 and will update their corresponding record to the database table with value of 1. So the unchecked check boxes value i want that time when i submit the form with 0. and update their corresponding record in the database table with value 0.

Comment: Means i have 10 Record of users. Every record have their UserId and name. With Every Record I have Two check Boxes as show in code. so total check boxes i have 20

I want when i checked 7 check boxes Randomly. so these seven corresponding record will be updated with 1 value in the database table. and other 13 Unchecked check boxes corresponding record in the database table should be updated with 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is actually very simple to do. Start with a basic form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkboxes[]" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkboxes[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkboxes[]">
</form>
```

Then build in your back-end with `php`

```
if(isset($_POST['my_checkboxes'])){
   foreach($_POST['my_checkboxes'] as $key => $val){
        // Update database with $val Update DB set col = '$val' (use prepared statements for security)
   }
}
```

This code can be much improved, but this will give you the general idea. One ***important*** note, php will only pass the *checked* checkboxes. So, keep that in mind.

One way to overcome this potential issue is to add a hidden input for each checkbox that you have, so your forum might change to look like this (note: removing brackets from the `name` attribute):

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox1" value="sent" checked>
    <input type="hidden" name="my_checkbox1" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_checkboxe2">
    <input type="hidden" name="my_checkbox2" value="">
</form>
```

Now, using PHP you would just have to determine if the value is `sent` or if the value is `empty`. If the value is `sent`, it's checked, otherwise it's unchecked.

Comment: Yes i know that we can only pass the checked checkboxes values. But my problems is that. i want both. like you have give me an example. i checked the first one checkbox and got its value For example 1. So this time i want the other two checkbox value with 0.As this will done with hidden input field with same name as checkbox with value 0?

Comment: There is no limit of checkboxes. its up to my sql query that how much record its lying.

Comment: @MuhammadAtiq It doesn't matter how many you have. Just use PHP to dynamically create the check boxes. The solution I gave above *will* solve your initial issue.

Comment: For example if i get five check Boxes checked so in the array i get five checkboxes values. and 10 hidden fields values. I am confused can you check my code above? When i print the Post array. its Gives me 10 users record and 15 Record for checkbox 1. if five checkboxes checked.So how i match 15 checkbox1 array with 10 Users record.

Comment: You say that every checkbox have unique name? and their crossponding hidden field have unique name?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="check1[]" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value="1" <?php if($row_news1['house']=='1') echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>>
          <input type="hidden" name="check2[]" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="check2[]" value="1" <?php if($row_news1['add_item']=='1') echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>>

Comment: @MuhammadAtiq No, The hidden input field must **match** the name of its corresponding checkbox.

Comment: @MuhammadAtiq Let's talk in chat, you should have enough reputation in around 10 mins.

Comment: I have only 1 Reputation. which is not yet enough to chat

Comment: @MuhammadAtiq Start a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) and post your code there

Comment: Can you give me your skype id?

Comment: If you want to pay me for my time, then sure. Otherwise you're going to have to figure this one out from here

Comment: Yeah I can. Feel free to email me.

Comment: Give me your email id?

Comment: farina.evan@gmail.com